# How to create duplicate <tr> in <table> dynamically in laravel with help of count?

Tags: laravel, for-loop, html-table

I have one form with 2 input box.1. shareholders Count and  2.directors Count
User will fill that form with count of both the inputs. After that In second blade file where actual `table` is fillable.

I am sending my count in array with controller :

```
$data = array('shareholders'=>$request->com_shareholder_count,'directors_count'=>$request->directors_count);
return view('company_info',compact('data'));
```

In laravel blade `company_info` I have one static table.

```
<tr>
    <td>In respect of all directors</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Residential address:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>No of Shares:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>In respect of Shareholders</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Surname:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Forenames:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Title (if any):</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

**Now, As per my count of directors_count in array I have to create `<tr>` for directors_info, and same for shareholders_count.**

For example, if I get in array `$data['directors_count']` of 2 then table will generate two times of `<tr></tr>` till directors_info.

```
<tr>
    <td>In respect of all directors</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Residential address:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>No of Shares:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Residential address:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>No of Shares:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

And my format should be same as I have given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `@for` if the `directors_count` you're referring to is just an integer:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $item->directors_count; $i++)
    <tr>Repeating content here.</tr>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if all you mentioned in your question is what you really need.

Do:

```
@foreach($data as $item)
<tr>
    <td>In respect of all directors</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{{ $item->name }}:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{{ $item->address }}:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{{ $item->no_of_shares }}:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I dont know what items you have in your table... let me know if that helps

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i have static <td></td> as i mention in my question. I have just `dynamic count` .I have only $item->directors_count. with help of this count i want to duplicate entire <tr></tr>